# ¿Cómo indicar que una propiedad de una clase serializable en Json pueda ser null en C# 7.3?

Tags: json, null, c#-8.0, serializacion

Tengo que usar un endpoint de una WebApi y mandarle por Post un json con un objeto complejo (uso newtonsoft.json). El problema que me surge es que para hacer la serialización del objeto uso una clase y entre las propiedades hay algunas que podrían estar nulas.

En C# 8.0 o superior esto lo soluciono poniendo algo como esto:

`public int? rectificative_reason_code { get; set; }`

De esta forma y poniendo en las opciones de serialización del Json que me ignore los valores nulos con este código:

`var stringPayload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(factura,  new JsonSerializerSettings  { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore });`

No me incluye en el json esas propiedades cuando son nulas.

El problema está en que tengo que usar C# 7.3 ya que el proyecto está en .Net 4.6.1 y no puedo cambiarlo y en esa versión no se admiten los tipos nullables.

¿Cómo podría hacerlo? He visto por ahí que hay una propiedad JsonSerializerOptions.DefaultIgnoreCondition en la que podría intentar ponerle a esas propiedades un valor por defecto y que no salga al serizalizarla. ¿Es esta la forma correcta? ¿hay otra forma de que no me salgan esas propiedades al serializar el objeto?

Gracias

Comment: probaste con `public Nullable<string> rectificative_reason_code { get; set; }` ?? otra forma sería ocupar un diccionario, no una clase

Comment: he probado lo que comentas, pero me da el siguiente error:
Error CS0453 El tipo 'string' debe ser un tipo de valor que no acepte valores NULL para poder usarlo como parámetro 'T' en el tipo o método genérico 'Nullable<T>'

Comment: respecto al tema de usar un diccionario en vez de una clase. Es un objeto complejo con varias clases/subclases y unos 100 campos. Me parece poco manejable con un diccionario

Comment: Claro el error es porque string si acepta nulos (en cualquier versión de .net), por eso encuentro muy extraño el problema, porque no debería ser necesario ocupar ni nullable ni el `?`. Lo del diccionario es solo una idea, es el mismo trabajo que setear la clase, he incluso se puede crear de forma automática con reflection, pero depende de lo importante que sea para tu caso, quizás no vale la pena tanto trabajo

Comment: Tienes razón que ese campo String ya puede ser nullable. No elegí el mejor ejemplo, he probado lo que decías de Nullable<T> en un campo int y parece que sí que puede ser la solución. Muchas gracias, lo sigo comprobando y si ya funciona todo lo marco como solución

Comment: @Yussef `Nullable<T>` es exactamente lo mismos que `T?` y hasta C# 11 y .NET 6 no existían los tipos de referencia nullables. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/nullable-reference-types

Comment: @Mateo No es así. `Nullable<T>` existe desde hace mucho tiempo, más tarde se agregó el `T?` como azúcar sintáctico a lo primero. Antes y Después de C#11 los tipos de referencia aceptan valores null, lo que se agregó en C# 11 fue la configuración `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>` que produce un warning cuando un tipo puede ser null y este no se ha declaro explícitamente que puede serlo

Comment: @Yussef a lo que me refería es que no tenía ningún sentido usar nullable con una clase hasta que se agregó esa configuración que permite distinguir entre una referencia que uno espera que sea null y una que no.

Comment: @Mateo Aahh si, exactamente eso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tal como indica el compañero Yussef en los comentarios.

La respuesta es utilizar **Nullable** en la propiedad correspondiente. Por ejemplo:

```
 public Nullable<int> rectified_base_amount { get; set; }
```

En tipos que no permitan **null** como **int**.

Muchas gracias Yussef, tu ayuda me ha sido de mucha utilidad.